# Prevent multiple selection for each row with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, row

I'm very new to Javascript. I want to avoid multiple selection for each "row". I found an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LrfNw/) but it remove attributes of all the selects in the page. I tried to tweak it to support only the table row but no such luck. Could someone please help! Below is the code snippet.

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var ary = new Array();
    $('select option:selected').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
            ary.push($(this).val());
        }
    });
    $('select option').each(function() {
        if ($.inArray($(this).val(), ary) > -1) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});​
```

This is my table structure

```
<tr>
   <td class="col-md-6">
       <select name="from[]" class="form-control single-select" id="from">
          <?php foreach($arrStops as $a){?>
               <option value="<?php echo implode($a) ?>"> <?php echo implode($a) ?></option>
         <?php } ?>
       </select>
   </td>
   <td class="col-md-6">
        <select name="to[]" class="form-control single-select" id="to">
          <?php foreach($arrStops as $a){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo implode($a) ?>"> <?php echo implode($a) ?></option>
          <?php } ?>
        </select>
  </td>
```

Comment: Please show relevant html structure

Comment: Just added the structure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any html shown I will assume the following would do what you need.

You want to isolate instances in that row by first traversing up to the `<tr>` using [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and then looking inside that `<tr>` for `<select>` elements that only exist in that row using [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$('select').change(function() {
    // isolate row instance
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');

    var ary = new Array();
    // only look inside row
    $row.find('select option:selected').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
            ary.push($(this).val());
        }
    });
    $row.find('select option').not(':selected').each(function() {
        if ($.inArray($(this).val(), ary) > -1) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: Remember this pattern...it is very common for repeating structures in a page

Comment: Thank you sensei! im still a noob